# How to prevent computer from taking some IP address

Tags: networking, ip

Imagine you got a network to which other users can connect with their PC's, you have set up some rules, for example there is a DHCP server that gives addresses 192.168.2.100 - .254 and first 100 addresses are reserved for people who want static IPv4 address.

How is it technically possible to prevent someone from taking some other IPv4 address? How could you restrict someone to use only a specific IP?

How do for example ISP enforce people to use only that public IP they got assigned? For example I have a server in server room and I was granted N IPv4 addresses, I received a list of all IPv4 addresses that I am allowed to use (they are all public IPv4 that can be accessed over internet). I didn't try to take any other IP than I am allowed because that would likely violate some rule and they might shut the server off so I am not even going to try that, but just out of curiosity, is this even technically possible to restrict somehow? How?

Comment: Are you asking this question from a network standpoint or server standpoint? It really depends on the way the network is setup. But since you said it's DHCP, MAC address filtering comes to mind.

Comment: Network standpoint. I would like to know how someone who is maintaining a network can prevent a device that is either physically (over a cable) or wirelessly connected from abusing it by for example taking an IP address that is dedicated for a different device and so on. I don't have any such a network, this is just a hypothetical question asked out of curiosity.

Comment: If you want an answer from a network perspective, it may be better to post this on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the appropriate hardware, this is quite easy to do. A managed switch will allow you to assign one or more IPs to a (physical) port, and will block traffic coming from any other IP on that port. You can also use a different network interface per computer on your server, though that may prove quickly more costly.

Lacking such hardware, the best you can do is MAC filtering and block traffic coming from an IP which is not associated with the MAC. This is doable using iptables on Linux. Be aware though that faking a MAC address is quite easy.

This won't prevent the computer from 'taking' the IP in that it can still be set statically on the interface, however all packets using that IP will be dropped, so it's not very useful.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to prevent a computer from using a different IP address. You can however, assign a specific IP address to a computer via DHCP based on the MAC address so when that computer requests an IP from the DHCP server they get that same one every time.

I will give you some possibilities below, but keep in mind that it would not prevent someone from assigning any static IP address they choose and possibly causing a duplicate IP on the network.

1. [DHCP reservations](http://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=137180) - This approach would use each computers mac address to "reserve" or "lease" a specific IP address to that device. It's not a whitelist or blacklist approach and any computer could get assigned an IP on the network. I believe this is only used with home type routers.
2. [MAC address filtering](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_filtering) - Similar to a DHCP reservation except the mac addresses are added to a whitelist or blacklist to allow/deny access to the network.

**EDIT :**
As I thought more about this there is actually a way to prevent changing the IP address but **not solely from the network side**. If the computers were on a domain a system administrator could lock down parts of the operating system such as network adapter settings, command-line, etc via Active Directory group policies.

Comment: Hmm, I think my question isn't written properly, I would tweak it later but first I need to figure out how to formulate it. I don't care about high level things like OS, I only consider this from network point of view. Let's say there is a device which is misbehaving, it steals IP address of some service, and wants to do something very nasty. How would you deal with it, other than unplugging the cable? There must be some way, because nobody has the power to unplug cable of any device on the internet.

Comment: There clearly must be a way to low-level block the device which is doing something wrong on network, such as taking IP address that it isn't suppose to take and this block needs to happen much sooner than other devices on the network get affected by this

Comment: Also keep in mind that even Mac address can be easily changed. You can do this even in virtual box, when you create virtual machine, you will see on your router and other network devices that they will see the Mac address of your virtual machine just as you changed it. It's just a number that is transmitted over the cable, both IP and Mac address can be abused easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Even in my home pppoe account I have set up a static IP while only being provisioned for dynamic ip. Only problem is ip conflicts.

Comment: If this is not possible, how would ISP prevent users from for example taking an IP of some public web server, such as google's? I suppose that network infrastructure they have would probably cut you off if you tried this, but I don't know, hence I ask here.

Comment: If you are on the same subnet as Google Web server, this might be possible, but it would cause an IP conflict. I think that routes are only set up to your is for your isps registered IPs, so you could take any other address from your isps block.

Answer (score 0):

On an ISP level you can give yourself any IP address you like, but only ones actually assigned to you will route, the rest will get no return traffic. They wont ban you, it just wont work.

Locally, its a little more tricky. It may be possible to block non DHCP clients, but really you just want to VLAN out guest machines so they cant cause any trouble.